# Out of memory in Matlab - how to do in-place operation on matrix elements?

Tags: matlab, matrix, out-of-memory, in-place

I am loading a quite large matrix into Matlab. Loading this matrix already pushes Matlab to its limits - but it fits.

Then I do the following and I get an out-of-memory error.

`data( :, 2:2:end, :, : ) = - data( :, 2:2:end, :, : );`

Is Matlab allocating a new matrix for this operation? I would assume this operation would not need extra memory. How do I force Matlab to be more efficient for this?

Bonus question:

'data = permute(data,[1 2 3 4 5 12 8 7 6 9 10 11]);'

Can matlab do this in-place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few constraints (further to those from Loren's block cited by John):

- Your code must be running inside a function
- You must have no other aliases to 'data'

The 'aliases' thing is both important and potentially hard to get right. MATLAB uses copy-on-write, which means that when you call a function, the argument you pass isn't duplicated immediately, but might be copied if you modify it within the function. For example, consider

```
x = rand(100);
y = myfcn(x);
% with myfcn.m containing:
function out = myfcn(in)
  in(1) = 3;
  out = in * 2;
end
```

In that case, the variable `x` is passed to `myfcn`. MATLAB has value semantics, so any modifications to the input argument `in` must not be seen in the calling workspace. So, the first line of `myfcn` causes the argument `in` to become a *copy* of `x`, rather than simply an alias to it. Consider what happens with `try`/`catch` - this can be an in-place killer, because MATLAB has to be able to preserve values if you error out. In the following:

```
% consider this function
function myouterfcn()
  x = rand(100);
  x = myfcn(x);
end
% with myfcn.m containing
function arg = myfcn( arg )
  arg = -arg;
end
```

then, that *should* get in-place optimisation for `x` in `myouterfcn`. But the following can't:

```
% consider this function
function myouterfcn()
  x = rand(100);
  x = myfcn(x);
end
% with myfcn.m containing
function arg = myfcn( arg )
  try
    arg = -arg;
  catch E
    disp( 'Oops.' );
  end
end
```

Hope some of this info helps...

Comment: Very nice answer. I checked the code, and I do not think it is an alias problem.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab does support in place operations.  Here's a discussion:  http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/03/22/in-place-operations-on-data/.  Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a good way to know what MATLAB is really doing under the sheets. I would recommend that you:

1. Make sure you `clear` any variables that aren't in use before trying the operation.
2. If you're still running out of memory, write and compile a simple mex file to do the operation in place. With a massive array and your specialized requirement, it'd probably be faster than MATLAB's approach too.

Likewise, you could write your own permutation algorithm as a .mex file in C if you require that it be done in-place (i.e. you're running out of memory again).

Comment: Not sure that a MEX function will help, because I don't think you can force it to use the same memory for the inputs and outputs of a MEX function.